# CONSULTA: Error al hacer el Update-Database por problemas con llaves foraneas

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

Buen@s días, tardes o noches, estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto de prueba haciendo un inventario. Estoy trabajando en C# ASP.Net Core 2.0
Tengo las siguientes clases:
Inventario
Clientes
Proveedores
Ventas
Productos

Hice el Update-Database y todo salió normal, luego pensé que así como hacía salidas del inventario, también debía hacer entradas a este mismo por lo que creé mi modelo Entradas, que basicamente hace lo mismo que ventas pero en vez de restar, suma al inventario, pero al momento de hacer mi Update-Database me aparece el siguiente error:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Entradas_Proveedor_ProveedorId' on table 'Entradas' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Estas son mis clases:
CLASE PRODUCTO:

```
public class Producto
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string ReferenciaFabrica { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string ReferenciaLocal { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double PrecioCompra { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double PrecioVenta { get; set; }

    public int MarcaId { get; set; }
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public int TipoFiltroId { get; set; }

    public Marca Marca { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
    public TipoFiltro TipoFiltro { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Ventas> Ventas { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entradas> Entradas { get; set; }
}
```

CLASE PROVEEDOR

```
public class Proveedor
{
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "{0} solo puede contener caracteres")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "{0} solo puede contener caracteres")]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(70, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Producto> Producto { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entradas> Entradas { get; set; }
}
```

CLASE ENTRADAS:

```
public class Entradas
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int EntradaID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaCompra { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }


    public int ProductoId { get; set; }
    public Producto Producto { get; set; }

    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
}
```

CLASE INVENTARIO:

```
public class Inventario
{
    [Required]
    public int InventarioID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaInventario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Stock { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaSalida { get; set; }

    public int ProductoId { get; set; }
    public Producto Producto { get; set; }

}
```

No sé qué hacer para actualizar mi base de datos y empezar a insertar datos, espero su ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: porque hay un modelo distinto para entradas? no deberias directamente modificar el producto y hacer la actualizacion sobre el?

Comment: Lo tengo pensado así: Almaceno mis productos, luego los ingreso una vez al inventario para después por medio de los modelos Entradas y Salidas se actualice en el inventario, eso lo hago más que todo para hacer un reporte al final de las entradas, con sus fechas, quién fue el proveedor, etc, etc, etc

Comment: o sea, hay una tabla de movimientos? tal vez deberias mostrar tambien tus tablas y sus relaciones, a mi no me queda claro donde puede estar tu error y como estas tratando de hacer esto. Usa el boton [edit] y agrega la info a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya puse la tabla de Inventario

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es común en ASP.Net este tipo de errores o advertencias se producen para que sepas que hay relaciones entre tablas que pueden traer la eliminación en Casacada de datos, osea lo que te dice ese error es que si eliminas un Proveedor se eliminarán todas las Entradas que tengan ese ProveedorId. Para solucionar esto puedes ir a la ultima migración creada cuando cambiastes tu modelo al crear la clase Entradas y busca el bloque de código donde se declara la Tabla Entrada. Te pongo un ejemplo de lo que debes ver

En la carpeta Migrations de tu proyecto selecciona la ultima migración y busca donde se ha declarado la Tabla Entrada.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Entradas",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                ....
                ....
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Entradas", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Entradas_Proveedor_ProveedorId",
                    column: x => x.ProveedorId,
                    principalTable: "Proveedores",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
            });
```

en `table.ForeignKey()` debes tener declarado: `name:"FK_Entradas_Proveedor_ProveedorId".... onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade` cámbialo por `ReferentialAction.NoAction` y prueba tu Update-Database. Espero te sea de ayuda